# Invertibility and solution of equation with compound circular matrix

Tags: calculus, matrices, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus, circulant-matrices

Given the matix C, which can be represented as: C=A*P + B*Q (C=(A|B)), where A and B are circulant matrices; P and Q are projectors (P projects first half of matrix vectors, Q projects second half). 
C consists of two circular matricex. 
A is invertible matrix. 
C also can be represented as: $$C=A(P+A^{-1}BQ)$$. All matrix is invertible, if $$(P+A^{-1}BQ)$$ is invertible. So, we have scheme of matrix:
\begin{bmatrix}
    I       & PA^{-1}BQ \\
    O       & QA^{-1}BQ \\
\end{bmatrix}
Where I - identity matrix, O is zero matrix. 
How can I obtain the conditions of reversibility and solve equation Cx=b ?